# History Server not starting on cloudera Hadoop

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, cloudera

I have setup the 'hadoop' by following the instructions given in [here](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/11/building-and-deploying-mr2/). 
I downloaded and deployed it successfully and can able to run all the daemons except historyserver and run the example programs.
when I run sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start historyserver, the following error is displayed.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: historyserver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: historyserver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: historyserver.  Program will exit.
```

Can anyone do help me in this issue?

Answer (score 5):

To start the history server, it seems that the command is now:

```
./sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```